# (Bigish source code) Beginners Java project, lots of problems, has to do with encrypting alphabet

Tags: java, string, encryption, cryptography

Okay so my CS teacher recommended [this project](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.acsl.org%2Facsl%2Fsample_ques%2Fc_1_code_int.pdf) to do outside of class in our free time for practice if we wanted to get a little deeper into what we've been learning. I've spent almost all of today outside of class trying to do it, and I feel like no matter what I do I end up with 2 new problems springing up. I'm just going to dump the massive amount I have so far, right now it has all the parts to do everything, but some of them are broken.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encoderv2 {

    public static int position(String l) {
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int i = alphabet.indexOf(l) + 1;
        return i;
    }

    public static String back(int x) {
        String alphabet2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String z = alphabet2.substring(x-1, x);
        return z;
    }

    public static String[] charDivider(String l3) {
        String[] characters = new String[l3.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < l3.length(); i++) {
            characters[i] = l3.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        return characters;

    }

    public static int[] positionSetter(String[] x, String p) {
        int[] positions = new int[p.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
            positions[i] = position(x[i]);
        }
        return positions;
    }

    public static int[] newPosition(int[] x1, String l1) {
        int[] positions2 = new int[l1.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < l1.length(); i++) {
            if (x1[i] <= 5) {
                positions2[i] = x1[i] * 2;
            } else if (x1[i] > 5 && x1[i] < 11) {
                positions2[i] = (x1[i] % 3) * 5;
            } else if (x1[i] > 10 && x1[i] < 16) {
                positions2[i] = (int) (x1[i] / 4) * 8;
            } else if (x1[i] > 15 && x1[i] < 21) {
                positions2[i] = (((x1[i] % 10) + ((x1[i] / 10) % 10)) * 10) % 26;
            } else if (x1[i] > 20 && x1[i] <= 27) { // U IS 21
                for(int e = 1;e < 14; e++) {
                    int factor = 0;
                    if(x1[i] % e == 0) {
                        factor = e;
                    }
                    positions2[i] = factor;
                }
                                                        // 22-11,23-dne,24-12,25-5,26-13
            }
        }
        return positions2;
    }

    public static String[] backtoLetters(int[] q, String line) {
        String[] letters2 = new String[line.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            letters2[i] = back(q[i]);
        }
        return letters2;
    }

    public static void printCode(String[] x2, String l2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < l2.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(x2[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter any number of letters to be encoded");
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] chars = charDivider(line);
            int[] positions = positionSetter(chars, line);
            int[] newPositions = newPosition(positions, line);
            String[] encodedLine = backtoLetters(newPositions, line);
            printCode(encodedLine, line);

        }

    }

}
```

So the two parts i'm having problems with right now are my back method, which turns the number I get from performing the operation on it back into a letter. If I put a space before the String alphabet and do indexOf(x,x+1) it works fine except for when the value is 0, then it just comes back a space. But if I get rid of the space it will somehow never return the value I want, and right now returns an error for some values (I have tried x+1. x-1 etc..) So I have no idea what i'm doing wrong

The second thing I am having difficulties with is finding a numbers greatest factor, multiplying it by 12 and then finding where that loops back onto the alphabet (mod 26), honestly here I just have no idea and it is giving me a headache...

If you see anything else wrong with my code (doesn't have to be related), maybe just something that will make it more efficient/less messy so people will hate me less when I get a job in the field that'd be great too :)

Comment: I am not sure how you convert your characters to numbers, but did you know that you can interpret a `char` as an `int`? You can get a mapping A -> 1, B -> 2, ... by doing: `((int)c)-64` where `c` is your `char`. Well... so much for type-safety, but at least, working directly with numbers seeems to be much simpler. For each character, you can then: "cast" it to an `int`, as described; If the value is less than or equal to 5, then multiply by to; else if (and so on); compute the result modulo 26; add 64; cast back to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code a little to show how to efficiently program this in Java. This should also make the utility functions more easy to read. I'll give you some hints about the encoding function below that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EncodervOwl {

    public static int position(char c) {
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character out of range");
        }
        return c - 'A' + 1;
    }

    public static char back(int i) {
        if (i < 1 || i > 'Z' - 'A' + 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character out of range");
        }
        return (char) ('A' + i - 1);
    }

    public static int[] positionSetter(String s) {
        int[] positions = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            positions[i] = position(s.charAt(i));
        }
        return positions;
    }

    public static String backtoLetters(int[] p) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(p.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            s.append(back(p[i]));
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    public static void printCode(int[] positions) {
        System.out.print("Positions: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(positions[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] newPosition(int[] p) {
        int[] p2 = new int[p.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            if (p[i] <= 5) {
                p2[i] = p[i] * 2;
            } else if (p[i] > 5 && p[i] < 11) {
                // not reversible (6 and 9 map to 0, 7 and 10 to 1 etc)
                p2[i] = (p[i] % 3) * 5;
            } else if (p[i] > 10 && p[i] < 16) {
                p2[i] = (int) (p[i] / 4) * 8;
            } else if (p[i] > 15 && p[i] < 21) {
                // from 1..26 to 0..25
                p2[i] = (((p[i] % 10) + ((p[i] / 10) % 10)) * 10) % 26;
            } else if (p[i] > 20 && p[i] <= 27) { // U IS 21
                for(int e = 1;e < 14; e++) {
                    int factor = 0;
                    if(p[i] % e == 0) {
                        factor = e;
                    }
                    p2[i] = factor;
                }
            }
        }
        return p2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter any number of letters to be encoded");
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            int[] positions = positionSetter(line);
            printCode(positions);
            int[] newPositions = newPosition(positions);
            printCode(positions);
            String encodedLine = backtoLetters(newPositions);
            System.out.println(encodedLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Now it seems you try and use a range from 1 to 26 to perform your [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). Note that usually, in mathematics, calculations are usually done *modulo the size of the alphabet*. That would be 26 in your case. This maps values to a group of numbers from **0** to **size - 1** (inclusive). Again, in your case that would be **0** to **25**. So where you first have 1..26 you now have 0..25. You should always start with index 0, never 1, it's not mathematically sound!

Furthermore, you need to think very hard which calculations are reversible and which are not. If you do `x1 % 3` for instance then both the values 6 and 9 will return 0. So in that case you lose information and you cannot reverse the encryption operation.

Good luck with your project, you should be able to focus a bit more on the actual encryption now.

Comment: Warning: I've removed your comment. Be sure to write comments you understand later on. They tend to remain in source code, and then - often years after - you spend ages trying to figure out what they meant (trust me on this :) ).

Comment: Wow thank you! I love that you gave me hints instead of just doing it, because I know from experience when someone just does it I can study it all I want, but i'll never learn as much as actually doing it

Comment: You're welcome. Note that these kind of questions are more on topic on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stackoverflow is meant for concise programming questions.

Comment: Wow sorry haha, I guess I just instinctively came here when I ran into trouble because whenever I google a problem Stackoverflow is usually the first helpsite with the answer to pop up

Comment: That's OK, SO has a large attraction, a bit too strong maybe. Of course if you progress beyond substitution ciphers, don't forget about sites as crypto.stackexchange.com and security.stackexchange.com neither.

Comment: Oooh, cryptography is actually somewhat interesting to me so I will probably take a look at those outside of class :) Thanks again!

Comment: The best way of saying thanks on SO is to upvote, or - if you asked the question - to accept it by clicking one of the V-marks next to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advise treating your input characters as int as the comment suggests - will make the mathamaticaly operations (especially the 'wraparound' % 26 issue you're running into)

```
     for (int x = 0;x<line.length();x++)
        {
            int NumericalValue = line.charAt(x) - 64;
       // code continues
```

Because the integer value of 'A' = 65, this will give you 'A' = 1, 'B' = 2 and so on. (For more char-to-int info google ascii/unicode charts)

I've quickly written out a solution to this problem, but I don't want to give you the solution directly, so if you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Wow that will make things sooooo much easier! Haha thank you SO much. Are there any other big problems you see with my code that can quickly be condensed by something simple I might just not know yet? (Learning new things is kinda the point haha) I feel like my if else if statement is really cluttered for one, is that really the most effective way of checking all of the conditions?

Comment: I prefer using, 'A' = 0, which is coded more transparently as: `int NumericalValue = line.charAt(x) - 'A';` without having to use the "magic number" 64.